# Cannot view field names in certain PDF files

Tags: pdf

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro 9.

I have downloaded several PDF files from the IRS website (for a website project I'm working on.) All of these IRS forms have fillable fields. I need to check out the names for each of these fields. The way I usually do this is by going to "Forms"/"Add or Edit Fields", then I can see all of the field names for each of the text boxes.

The problem is some of these PDF forms will not allow me to view this. If I goto Forms the "Add or Edit fields" menu option is either missing or disabled. I tried making a copy of the offending forms (Save a Copy), but this did not always work (sometimes it did work). I've also searched online but could not find a solution thus far. :(

In Document Properties the Security Method is set to "No Security".

Any ideas on how I can view the field names for these text boxes on these forms? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRS no longer has PDF forms.

The IRS now has XFA forms, wrapped in PDF, so that Adobe Reader can display them.

XFA forms are created using LiveCycle Designer, which used to be thrown after the buyers of Acrobat Pro for Windows. With Acrobat XI, this is no longer the case, and LCD is now sold separately (if you have a valid license of Acrobat X or older, you may be entitled for a free (or at least discounted) license for LCD. Contact Adobe (sales) support about your options.

One workaround, you can try, is to fill out the form, and then try to export the data as XML. That should give you the field names. You may first have to remove the Extended Rights for Reader by opening the form and then select Save a Copy…

And finally, you can complain at the IRS for giving up a widely used standard for forms…

Comment: Thanks Max. So it sounds like some of the newer forms may appear to be PDFs, but I will not be able to look at the field names thru Acrobat Pro 9? I tried the export, as suggested, but it didn't appear to give field names. Ultimately I'm trying to programmatically do a "mail merge" like type of thing with data and the PDF forms. I need the field names to do this. The code works fine with standard PDFs.

Comment: You're welcome, @WebDevGuy. As said, the forms come along as PDF. You can have a quick look at the document properties and see how they have been created. I bet that "LiveCycle Designer…" is mentioned. With the export, it really should be a connection between field name and field value; this is the case in any kind of export, because otherwise, it would not be possible to make an association between field value and field name…

Comment: You're correct! The PDF Producer is LiveCycle Designer. Thanks! I typed in some sample data and did an Export/XML 1.0. Looking at the results I can see the input. I'm using iTextSharp for the PDF manipulation. So I have to figure out a way to utilize this info. If you have any ideas please let me know. Sample portion of XML output: <Div><P>City or town, state, and ZIP code</P>HERE IS THE TEST DATA!!!!!</Div>

Comment: If you are using iTextSharp, you'd have to find out to which extent it does support XFA; I don't know, but there are good people around here in Stackoverflow who DO know. One thing I do not know either is whether the IRS is actually sucking the data out of the filled forms. If you have a suspicion that they do not, and iTextSharp can not give what you need, you'd still have the possibility to refry the XFA form, and add your own fields (with your own field names) to it. (but that would be a "last straw" solution…)

Comment: Thanks for all your advice @MaxWyss!

Answer (score 2):

You may try to upload the PDF to [this](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/demos/assistant-demo/) product demo. If the form is a static one (kind of fallback for XFA forms), you will be able to see the field names. If it is a dynamic XFA form you may try [this one](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/demos/php-xfa-demo/).